# Can I submit an unofficial TOEFL score report if the official one won't be received by the university before the deadline?

Tags: graduate-admissions, language-exams, deadlines, toefl

It's been 8 days since my TOEFL scores were sent to me by ETS and I chose for them to be sent directly to the university I am applying. However, the official score reports won't be sent there before the deadline. Is it okay to copy-paste (since there is not a "print" option) and upload the scores that were electronically sent to me 10 days after the test date and notify the university about the delivery of the official score reports? Also, will I be notified by ETS when the university receives the official score reports?

Comment: The best way is to call the institute and ask as some have an overall deadline for all documents and some don't. In my institute (US), it's common that the TOEFL or reference letters come after the official due date. We usually just hold on the review process before everything is in. But do check with the school. As for ETS notification, I do not remember they notified me, but it's prudent to call the admission office after a sensible duration and check if they got it. A copy of your score can be attached but do know that it is not treated as the official one. It's simply just an IOU.

Comment: @Penguin_Knight Thanks for the response. I suspected that  it would not be treated as the official one and I am currently thinking of ordering via e-mail an official score report to upload so that the review process will not be delayed.

Comment: @Penguin_Knight Could you make that an answer?

Answer (score 2):

In my experience, universities don't have a deadline for official scores. They do however have a deadline for when you should have taken the exam. If you took the exam before the deadline, they either know that the scores will arrive before they actually start reviewing your application, or they don't consider the scores until later in the process. You can always contact them and ask if they would like an unofficial score report, but if you took the exam before the deadline it will not be a problem.

Answer (score 1):

ETS says "Official score reports will be sent to your designated recipients approximately 13 days after you take the test." at [this link](https://www.ets.org/toefl/ibt/scores/send/)

That means, if your deadline is 20 days from now, and you take your TOEFl today, then score would be sent within 13 days (7 days before the deadline.) and finally will be received by the university after 13+7 days (it might take more). You can mail the university asking them to consider your report if they receive it wthin 2-3 days. They can wait for 2-3 days, if requested, but totally depends on the school. Talk to them, request them. Otherwise, your application will be considered as INCOMPLETE! and it would be considered in the next Round.

I don't think that the candidate is intimated about the delivery of the report as they send it via postal mail.

Comment: The official report is not received but sent 13 days after the test date. The delivery date depends on the location. For the US, about 7 additional days are needed while for locations outside the US, 4-6 additional weeks are needed.

Comment: Ohh, I interpreted it wrong. Answer Updated. Thanks!